# Prove $\sum_{n≥1}\frac{\sin n}{n}= \frac{1}{2}(\pi-1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I recently learnt that sums of sine and cosine series whose arguments are in arithmetic progression can be evaluated using complex numbers. I modified it a little; like below I divided it by the argument of sine, and didn't expected a closed form sum. But surprisingly , Wolfram calculator gives this nice answer for it's sum.
$$\sum_{n≥1}\frac{\sin n}{n}= \frac{1}{2}(\pi-1)$$

I've never encountered such series so I'm interested in knowing that what are the methods using which we can prove these sums ( assuming the result given by calculator as true ). Thanks !

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/227751/42969 and the linked questions.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3361618/42969

Comment: Are you familiar with Fourier series?

Comment: @MartinR  I tried scrolling but these questions didn't appeared on related questions while I was writing. Thanks!

Comment: Found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn≥1%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin%20n%7D%7Bn%7D%3D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D(%5Cpi-1)%24)

Comment: @AjinShajiJose I'm a high school dropper .I have heard about that it's used in quantum mechanics but as said , I've only "heard" and not familiar with either of them. I hope to learn in future. Thanks for telling me the technique.

Comment: I found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/proving-that-the-sequence-f-nx-sum-limits-k-1n-frac-sinkxk-is

Comment: Is the domain for n assumed to be integers, natural numbers?
In other words what is the significance of $n \geq 1$ instead of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$

Comment: And for the record this is a duplicate question right?  @MartinR 's linked questions.

Comment: @nickalh: that notation is standard, I would say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}n=-\ln(1-z)$$ for $|z|<1.$

I think due to Dirichlet test, we can use this formula for $z=e^{ix}\neq1$. Then,

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin nx}n &= \frac1{2i}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{ixn}}n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-ixn}}n\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{2i}\ln\left(\frac{1-e^{-ix}}{1-e^{ix}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi-x}{2}
\end{align}$$
which is true for $0<x<2\pi$.

Comment: You pulled that out of a hat! You have to be explicit with your limits when complex logarithms are concerned. In particular, $|e^{ix}|$ and $|e^{-ix}|$ are _not_ less than $1$, so you can't just plug them into your first equation.

Comment: $\ln1=0$, $\ln(-1)=\pi i$.